# Error: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, retrofit, rx-java

**I have an error when i try to read a json.**

**Json**

```
    {
       "pratos":[
          {
             "IDITENS_VENDA":539,
             "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO":"X BAICON",
             "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE":1,
             "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO":14.5,
             "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA":97
          },
          {
             "IDITENS_VENDA":540,
             "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO":"ESPETINHO",
             "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE":1,
             "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO":55,
             "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA":97
          }
       ]
    }
```

**Api**

```
@GET("itens_mesa")
    fun ListItensMesa(@Query("idmesas")idmesas : String?):Observable<List<Itens_Mesa>>
```

**`class`**

```
class Itens_Mesa(
    @SerializedName("DESCRICAO_PRODUTO")
    val DESCRICAO_PRODUTO : String,
    @SerializedName("ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE")
    val ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE : String,
    @SerializedName("PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO")
    val PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO : Double,
    @SerializedName("COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO")
    val COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO : String,
    @SerializedName("COMPLEMENTO_VALOR")
    val COMPLEMENTO_VALOR : Double,
    @SerializedName("IDITENS_VENDA")
    val IDITENS_VENDA : String,
    @SerializedName("VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA")
    val VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA : Double,
    @SerializedName("Resposta")
    val Resposta : String
)

function Lista_Itens(){
        disposable =  client.ListItensMesa(idmesas)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result -> Log.e(" Result " , result[0].DESCRICAO_PRODUTO) },
                { error -> println(" Erro não esperado! " + error.printStackTrace()) }
            )
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**When I read json that way it works perfectly**

```
[
    {
        "IDITENS_VENDA": 539,
        "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "X BAICON",
        "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
        "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 14.5,
        "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 97
    },
    {
        "IDITENS_VENDA": 540,
        "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "ESPETINHO",
        "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
        "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 55,
        "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 97
    }
]
```

Comment: can you the Json that you're receiving? also the entity that it's converted to.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question needs improvement. Please read: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hi Fabio. Please post both the code and error as text.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a list of "Itens_Mesa" objects, but in JSON your list of objects is an attribute of another object. If you can change your API call then change the response like what you have done in here.

```
[
    {
        "IDITENS_VENDA": 539,
        "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "X BAICON",
        "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
        "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 14.5,
        "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 97
    },
    {
        "IDITENS_VENDA": 540,
        "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "ESPETINHO",
        "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
        "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 55,
        "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 97
    }
]
```

If you cannot change API call then define another class as follow,

```
class Itens_Mesa_List_Object(
    @SerializedName("pratos")
    val INTENSE_MESA_LIST : List<Itens_Mesa>
)
```

change your call as follow,

```
**Api**
@GET("itens_mesa")
fun ListItensMesa(@Query("idmesas")idmesas: String?):Observable<Itens_Mesa_List_Object>
```

then you can print your result like this,

```
{ 
    result -> Log.e(" Result " , result.INTENSE_MESA_LIST[0].DESCRICAO_PRODUTO )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**thanks for the help i got the result. But I still had the following doubt and if the json is bigger with 2 []. How would it work?**

Example 2 Json

```
[
    {
        "pratos": [
            {
                "IDITENS_VENDA": 539,
                "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "X BAICON",
                "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
                "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 14.5,
                "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 97
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_VENDA": 540,
                "DESCRICAO_PRODUTO": "ESPETINHO",
                "ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE": 1,
                "PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO": 55,
                "VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA": 97
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "complementos": [
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 546,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 533,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 16,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "COM BIFÉ",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 8.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 547,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 533,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 15,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "COM FEIJOADA",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 5.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 548,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 533,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 7,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "OVO",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 1.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 549,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 533,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 6,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "BACON",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 3.5
            },
            {
                "IDITENS_COMPLEMENTO": 550,
                "ITENS_IDPEDIDOS": 533,
                "ITENS_IDCOMPLEMENTO": 17,
                "COMPLEMENTO_DESCRICAO": "COM ACOMPANHAMENTO",
                "COMPLEMENTO_VALOR": 8.5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**I created a separate class for each []. But it's not working**

```
class Itens_Mesa(
    @SerializedName("IDITENS_VENDA")
    val IDITENS_VENDA : String,
    @SerializedName("DESCRICAO_PRODUTO")
    val DESCRICAO_PRODUTO : String,
    @SerializedName("ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE")
    val ITENS_VENDA_QUANTIDADE : String,
    @SerializedName("PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO")
    val PRECOVENDA_PRODUTO : Double,
    @SerializedName("VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA")
    val VENDAS_VALOR_VENDA : Double
) {
    class Itens_Mesa_Pratos(
        @SerializedName("pratos")
        @Expose(serialize = false)
        val MESA_LIST_PRATOS: List<Itens_Mesa>
    )
}
```

**Api**

```
 @GET("itens_mesa")
    fun ListItensMesa(@Query("idmesas")idmesas : String?):Observable<Itens_Mesa.Itens_Mesa_Pratos>
```

**function**

```
fun Lista_Itens(){
        disposable =  client.ListItensMesa(idmesas)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result ->
                    Log.e(" Result " , result.INTENSE_MESA_LIST[0].DESCRICAO_PRODUTO)
//                    viewadapter = Itens_Mesa_Adapter(result.MESA_LIST_PRATOS,this)
                    recyclerViewItens_Mesa.adapter = viewadapter
                },
                {
                    error ->
                    println(" Erro não esperado! " + error.printStackTrace())
                })
    }
```

**Error Read Json**

```
W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:45)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12051)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12051)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:579)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
        ... 17 more
```